# Byte/Int Conversion

Tags: java, int, type-conversion, byte

So I am trying to take an int ex. 3240 and convert to a byte which prints -88.

```
        final int x = (int) (buffer[bufferIndex++] * 32767.0);
        System.out.println("1 " + x);
        byteBuffer[i] = (byte) x;
        System.out.println("2 " + (byte) x);
        System.out.println("3 " + (int) byteBuffer[i]);
```

I have problems converting back to a int from the byte. How do i take -88 and make it 3240 again?

Comment: You can't. The conversion from `int` to `byte` was lossy.

Comment: An `int` is 32 bits, and a `byte` is 8.  So to get your `int` back from a byte, all you have to do is take the 8 bits of the byte, and find the 24 bits you lost when you converted it to a byte.  So where are the 24 bits?  I dunno, maybe they fell out of your computer and onto the floor?

Answer (score 3):

From the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) regarding Narrowing Primitive Conversions

> A narrowing primitive conversion may lose information about the
>   overall magnitude of a numeric value and may also lose precision and
>   range.

When you converted the `int` value `3240` to the byte value `-88`, you lost information in the truncated bytes. The `int` value `10920` would also have converted to `-88`. So would tons of other `int` values.

There's no way to get `-88` back from `3240`.

Answer (score 0):

Other than Sotorios answer, this is what you can do for conversions:

byte to int

```
Byte b = new Byte(NUMBER);
int i = b.intValue();
```

int to byte

```
int i = NUMBER;
byte b = (byte) i;
```